# MySQL search and replace regex

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I'd like to remove the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags without hurting the inside tags for all occurrances of this kind of structure:

```
<ul class="listapdf">
<li><a href="something">something</a></li>
<li><a href="something">something</a></li>
</ul>
```

What command can I use in MySQL command line?

Comment: Perhaps, you should check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: **Don't** process xml/html/... with regexes, use tools like **xpath**...

Comment: How is this stored in MySQL?  You just have raw html in your database?

Comment: @Davon: is a Wordpress database. They are inside the post contents table.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's REGEXPs can locate rows, it cannot do substitutions.  Do the processing into your client code.